# how to connect mobile camera or other camera to the picture box in c#,winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Started learning c# from past 1 month,I have a question that whether is it possibility to connect and display mobile camera or other web camera in the picture box.,in c# .net framework in windows forms. thanks in advance

Comment: Look into AForge.Video.DirectShow and FilterInfoCollection as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to communicate with the camera.

I use this code to communicate with the camera.

```
public class CameraAPI
{
    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }

    [DllImport("avicap32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr capCreateCaptureWindowA(byte[] lpszWindowName, int dwStyle, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hWndParent, int nID);
    [DllImport("avicap32.dll")]
    public static extern bool capGetDriverDescriptionA(short wDriver, byte[] lpszName, int cbName, byte[] lpszVer, int cbVer);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, bool wParam, long lParam);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, short wParam, long lParam);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern bool DestroyWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    public const int WM_USER = 0x400;
    public const int WS_CHILD = 0x40000000;
    public const int WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000;
    public const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x2;
    public const int SWP_NOZORDER = 0x4;
    public const int WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT = WM_USER + 10;
    public const int WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT = WM_USER + 11;
    public const int WM_CAP_SET_CALLBACK_FRAME = WM_USER + 5;
    public const int WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW = WM_USER + 50;
    public const int WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWFORMAT = WM_USER + 45;
    public const int WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE = WM_USER + 52;
    public const int WM_CAP_START = WM_USER;
    public const int WM_CAP_SAVEDIB = WM_CAP_START + 25;
    public const int WM_CAP_EDIT_COPY = (WM_CAP_START + 30);


    private IntPtr hWnd;
    private IntPtr mControlPtr;
    private int mWidth;
    private int mHeight;

    public CameraAPI(IntPtr handel, int width, int height)
    {
        mControlPtr = handel; //handle of video dom
        mWidth = width; //video width
        mHeight = height; //video height
    }

    public void StartPreviewWebcam()
    {
        if (hWnd != null)
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);

        byte[] lpszName = new byte[100];
        byte[] lpszVer = new byte[100];
        capGetDriverDescriptionA(0, lpszName, 100, lpszVer, 0);
        hWnd = capCreateCaptureWindowA(lpszName, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, mWidth, mHeight, mControlPtr, 0);
        if (SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, 0, 0))
        {
            SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE, 100, 0);
            SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW, true, 0);
            IsAvailable = true;
        }
        else
        {
            IsAvailable = false;
        }
    }

    public void CloseWebcam()
    {
        SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT, 0, 0);
        IsAvailable = false;
    }

    public void SavePictureByPath(string path)
    {
        IntPtr hBmp = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(path);
        SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CAP_SAVEDIB, 0, hBmp.ToInt64());
    }
    
    public byte[] TakePicture()
    {
        byte[] imgByteArray = null;
        var path = Application.StartupPath + @"\Image.png";
        try
        {
            DeleteExist(path);
            SavePictureByPath(path);
           
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                using (Image img = Image.FromFile(path))
                {
                    imgByteArray = ImageToByteArray(img);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            var a = 1;
        }
        finally
        {
            DeleteExist(path);
        }


        return imgByteArray;
    }
    
    public void DeleteExist(string path)
    {
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Delete(path);
        }
    }
    
    public byte[] ImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This can't be the way.  Are there no reasonable API's hiding this complexity?

Answer (score 0):

You question is a bit too broad for this site. The answer is "Yes it is possible" but it is not as simple as writing a few lines of code in C#. You will need some kind of toolkit/library/framework that allows you to connect to the camera and display the video. There are tons of them out there, each having pros and cons, some simple, some complicated.

If you are using Visual Studio, in the Solution Explorer right-click on your Project name and select "Manage Nuget Packages". In the Window that opens select "Browse" and then type "camera" into the search box. You will see a number of packages that provide support for using cameras.

Comment: is there no obvious way to display video on a windows form for the purpose of capturing an image?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with finding a satisfying answer to this problem and ended up finding AForge.Video:

```
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;

namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ConnectToCamera();
        }

        void ConnectToCamera()
        {
            var pictureBox = new PictureBox()
            {
                Width = 640,
                Height = 480
            };

            // add pictureBox to the form
            this.Controls.Add(pictureBox);

            // connects to the camera and display video on the form (using AForge)
            var items = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            var videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(items[0].MonikerString);
            videoSource.NewFrame += (s, e) =>
            {
                pictureBox.Image = (Bitmap)e.Frame.Clone();
            };

            videoSource.Start();

        }
    }
}
```